# Mysql Filter Table with multiple values separated by semicolon

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter my table that the where clause has multiple value separated with semicolon. I am trying to use find in set but it does not give any output.

tblAddress:

```
Address       Mat           month
tblA           X            01
tblA           Y            01
tblB           Z            01
tblB           1            01
tblC           Y            01
tblC           J            01
tblD           M            01
tblD           S            01
tblA           X            02
tblA           Y            02
tblB           Z            02
tblB           1            02
tblC           Y            02
tblC           J            02
tblD           M            02
tblD           S            02
```

I am trying to filter it by month and address

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAddress 
WHERE month  BETWEEN "01" AND "02"
    AND month  BETWEEN "01" AND "02"
    AND FIND_IN_SET(Address, REPLACE("tblA;tblC", ';', ',') )
```

Current Output is no result showing

but my desired output

```
tblAddress

Address       Mat           Month
tblA           X            01
tblA           Y            01
tblC           Y            01
tblC           J            01
tblA           X            02
tblA           Y            02
tblC           Y            02
tblC           J            02
```

I am wondering if its possible using findinset or wherein? I will really appreciate any advice thank you

```
CREATE TABLE tblAddress (Address VARCHAR(20), Mat VARCHAR(20),month VARCHAR(20));
```

Comment: Do you have a SQL Fiddle or DB fiddle setup for this ?

Comment: I am sorry I dont have sql fiddle

Comment: I've had a go at answering, but I must confess I do not see where `s.Mall` comes from in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a single statement, but this is a pure MySQL solution:

```
SET @csv_list = REPLACE("tblA;tblC", ';', ',');
SET @expression = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM tblAddress WHERE Month IN (01,02) AND s.Mall IN (', @csv_list, ') ORDER BY Address');
PREPARE myquery FROM @expression;
EXECUTE myquery
```

The alternative would be to ensure your variable is pre-fixed and post-fixed with the semi-colon, then use something this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAddress 
WHERE Month IN (01,02) 
    AND LOCATE(CONCAT(';', s.Mall, ';'), ";tblA;tblC;" )
ORDER BY Address
```

Comment: thank you very much I really appreciate your time help thank you all your answer is really helpfiul and answered my question with an explanation thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAddress 
WHERE Month IN (01,02)
    AND Address IN ('tblA','tblc')
ORDER BY Address;
```

Comment: how does this account for using / converting a string with semi-colon separated values in it?